# Sublime 2 - Python - Passing command line args

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

Is there any way to pass command line arguments to a python script invoked with Ctrl+, f through SublimeREPL? i.e. pass args to something like:

```
def main():
  if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print 'usage: ./wordcount.py {--count | --topcount} file'
    sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Thanks